# django - How to display the user from the set of its user objects in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to display the username in the template by the set of its user objects passed from the view.

Suppose:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='user')
status_list = user.status_set.all()
```

Now, how do I get the username in the template as:

```
<h3>{{status_list.user.username}}</h3>
```

I know that I can pass the user of the status in the views:

```
{'status_user':user, 'status_list':status_list}
```

And then in templates as:

```
<h3>{{status_user.username}}</h3>
```

But I want to know if there is a way to just get the user with its set objects.You help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the user as is:

```
return render(request, 'statuses.html', {'status_user': user})
```

And in the template access to `status_set` property:

```
<h3>{{ status_user.username }}</h3>

<ul>
{% for status in status_user.status_set.all %}
    <li>{{ status }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

As alternative you can pass `status_list` to the template and show `user` of the first element:

```
<h3>{{ status_list.0.user.username }}</h3>
```

But you should be sure that `status_list` contains at least one record.

Comment: Yes. But I don't want to overwrite the variable for the requested user the `user` variable for the template.

Comment: Then pass the user as `status_user` template  variable. I edited the answer.

Comment: Yes. I think other than that, there is no other way. Thank you for your help.